# Which is the default submit button in Android when pressing GO button on keyboard?

Tags: android, web, android-softkeyboard

I have web app in Adnroid. I have two `submit` buttons inside. When I press `go` button on the keyboard one of then is always selected. Is there a way to manage which button is selected. How to determine which is the default `submit` button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the GO button should work similar to pressing enter on a computer keyboard. So the GO button is just submitting the form, it shouldn't be triggering any specific button on the form.